# How to map the config dir of the gentics/mesh docker image?

Tags: docker, gentics-mesh

I have tried to start mesh like this:

```
docker run -v /tmp/mesh/data:/mesh/data -v /tmp/mesh/conf:/mesh/conf -it -p 8080:8080 gentics/mesh
```

But the config directory stays empty. In the data directory everything is getting created.

We would need to access the config files to adjust the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://hub.docker.com/r/gentics/mesh/, the config directory should be mounted at `/mesh/config`, not `/mesh/conf`.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the manual:
https://getmesh.io/docs/beta/administration-guide.html#installdir

Answer (score 2):

I voted up the answer from [sneep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3592381/sneep), because this should work. Although it's not actually the exposed volume in the image, that *is* what they have in the description on the [hub.docker.com repo for mesh](https://hub.docker.com/r/gentics/mesh/).

The [Dockerfile](https://github.com/gentics/mesh/blob/master/server/Dockerfile) in the [gentics mesh repository](https://github.com/gentics/mesh) tells the story:

First with this bit:

```
RUN mkdir /data   && chown mesh: /data -R   && ln -s /data /mesh/data
RUN mkdir /config && chown mesh: /config -R && ln -s /config /mesh/config
```

And later these volumes are exposed:

```
VOLUME /data
VOLUME /config
VOLUME /elasticsearch/data
VOLUME /elasticsearch/config
```

I guess you could simply map to the `/data` and `/config` volumes, since they are what is exposed.

But as mentioned, previous answer should work just fine.